# I’m facing drastic slowness in my web Appa running on containerd and kubernetes vs docker

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containerd

I’m using containerd runtime for kubernetes ….I tried without setting resource limit and with limit  10 cores and 4Gi RAM

When I compare the performance in the same node, same container in docker vs kubernetes, the build load time is 17sec in docker and 55 sec in k8….
The page load time is 2 sec in docker and 30 sec in k8…

The container has tomcat, cassandra, redis in it.

What an I missing ?

Maybe containerd is slower than docker ?

Comment: I tried changing from containerd to cri-dockerd and still facing the same issue.